# Scrolling to a div inside a container with overflow-y in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

In an angular app I have two bootstrap columns - the left col contains a scrollable div with `overflow-y: auto;` - the right col is a set of links that are essentially bookmarks that jump to the sections within the left scrollable container.

As far as I can see I'm facing two challenges:

**1 - Setting up Angular to recognise I wish to scroll to page section when routing is enabled.**

This I've over come by using router options and fragments

```
const routerOptions: ExtraOptions = {
   useHash: false,
   scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
   anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
   scrollOffset: [0, 64]
 };

imports: [
      ...
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, routerOptions),
      ...
]
```

And the link:

```
<a [routerLink]='"."' fragment="uniquedivid">Link</a>
```

**2 - Getting a fragment / anchor to be scrolled into place when it's inside an overflow**

From what I've read on SO and other blogs I can see a varying array of ways to do this but most of them use JQuery (which I want to avoid as I'm using pure Angular) and none of these methods seem to compliment the route system in Angular.

I don't know if this makes a difference but my links come AFTER my overflow-ed div as shown below:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      <div id="overflow">
         <div id="section-1"></div>
         <div id="section-2"></div>
         <div id="section-3"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      <a [routerLink]='"."' fragment="section-1">Section 1</a> 
      <a [routerLink]='"."' fragment="section-2">Section 1</a>
      <a [routerLink]='"."' fragment="section-3">Section 3</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I feel like I'm along the right lines here there's just something I'm missing, or maybe I'm overcomplicating things and there's a simpler way I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you got a solution for it, but if I were you, I would have used a well organized npm module that can directly help you organize the breadcrumbs. If I understand the question correctly, you can use [angular-crumbs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-crumbs).

You can organize your routing like this :

```
export const rootRouterConfig: Routes = [  
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},  
    {path: 'home', ..., data: { breadcrumb: 'Home'}},  
    {path: 'about', ..., data: { breadcrumb: 'About'}},  
    {path: 'github', ..., data: { breadcrumb: 'GitHub'},  
        children: [  
            {path: '', ...},  
            {path: ':org', ..., data: { breadcrumb: 'Repo List'},  
                children: [  
                    {path: '', ...},  
                    {path: ':repo', ..., data: { breadcrumb: 'Repo'}}  
                ]  
        }]  
    }  
];
```

Then try to add the `breadcrumb`  selector in the component where your routes are destined to (when using bootstrap):

```
<breadcrumb #parent>  
  <ol class="breadcrumb">
    <ng-template ngFor let-route [ngForOf]="parent.breadcrumbs">
      <li *ngIf="!route.terminal" class="breadcrumb-item">
        <a href="" [routerLink]="[route.url]">{{ route.displayName }}</a>
      </li>
      <li *ngIf="route.terminal" class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">{{ route.displayName }}</li>
    </ng-template>
  </ol>
</breadcrumb>
```

There are other ways too, you can check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-crumbs) to implement.